# A more efficient way to parse dom elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some HTML I need to parse.

Basically I'm walking through the dom of a given element. Grabbing text nodes, and element nodes.

As I come across text nodes, I print them into a different element character by character. Each character is placed into it's own span, with its own style, which was taken from any element node found with a style attached.

So when an element node is found, it's style is applied to any text node detected until another element node is found and the old style is replaced with the new one.

The code below works. If you have a sentence or a short paragraph in the source element it reproduces the text accurately in less than a second. The longer the text gets the longer it takes (duh).

Interestingly, the more text that is already in the destination element, the longer it takes. So if I've ran this function 10 times on the same source element, with the same body of text being processed, it will run slower the 10th time through than the 1st time through, presumably because it's harder to render the text in an element that already has content.

Anyway, I really need to find a way to make this thing run faster.

Lastly, here is an example HTML snippet this thing might need to process:

```
<span style='blah: blah;'> Some text </span><span>Even more text </span> <p> stuff </p>
```

The resulting HTML would be:

```
<span style='blah: blah;'>S</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>o</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>m</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>e</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'> </span> 
<span style='blah: blah;'>t</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>e</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>x</span>
<span style='blah: blah;'>t</span> 
.......
```

Nothing fancy.

Here's the code:

Code:

```
ed.rta_to_arr_paste = function(ele, cur_style) {

    var child_arr = ele.childNodes;

    if(!(is_set(cur_style))) {
        cur_style = {};
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < child_arr.length; i++) {
        if(child_arr[i].nodeType == 1) {
            if(cur_style != child_arr[i].style) {
                cur_style = child_arr[i].style;
            }
        } else if(child_arr[i].nodeType == 3) {

            for(var n = 0; n < child_arr[i].nodeValue.length; n++) {

                var span = ed.add_single_char(child_arr[i].nodeValue.charAt(n), cur_style);
            }
        }
        ed.rta_to_arr_paste(child_arr[i], cur_style);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
One example of a system like this being used is in google docs.

When a user pastes text into the document, it's first rendered off screen, then processed with a function similar (I'm assuming) to this one. It then reprints the text in the document.
It all happens extremely fast (unless the text is very long).

Comment: Could you provide a demo? I somehow have trouble to understand what you want to do...

Comment: I can't post a demo due to a particularly stringent NDA. Check the edit, maybe it will help.

Comment: @Tyler: A demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ would be very helpful, even if you just stub out the proprietary functions so they do essentially the same processing without revealing your code.

Comment: What is `add_single_char` doing? How do you add the next character to the element? You can already save "some" time by reducing property access of elements.

Comment: It adds the character at child_arr[i].nodeValue.charAt(n) to the destination element which in this case is a div. It returns the span that was created to contain the character.

Comment: But how do you add it? Is the destination element inside the DOM tree? These are all things that influence performance...

Comment: @Stefan Don't do that. That kind of comment isn't welcome here, and circumventing the minimum length requirements is in violation of the rules.

Comment: The source element is a direct descendent of document (document.src_ele) and the destination is a decendent of the same document but much deeper within the dom. Does that answer your question? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: My tl;dr was relevant. The question is loaded with irrelevant information that I'm not going to waste my time reading. I could edit the question, but it would take too long to parse out the real issue.

Comment: I consider everything I've included in the question to be relevant, and you've wasted more time explaining your tl;dr comment than you would have taken by reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are directly inserting the new elements into the DOM tree, so I think you can get the best improvement by *not doing that*.

Avoid inserting a lot of elements one by one. Every time you insert an element, the browser has to recalculate the layout of the page and this takes time.

Instead, add the nodes to an element not in the DOM, the best would be using a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DocumentFragment), which can be created via [`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createDocumentFragment).

Then all you have to do is to insert this fragment and the browser only has to do one recalculation.

**Update:**

What you could also try is to use regular expressions to convert the text into the `span` elements.

```
var html = value.replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$1</span>")
```

<del>At least in my naive test (not sure if the testcases are good this way), it performs much better than creating `span` elements and adding them to the document fragment:</del>

**Update 2:** I adjusted the tests to also *set* the generated elements/string as content of an element and sadly, this takes away all the speed of using `replace`. But it might still be worth testing it:

http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-loop

---

You should also avoid repeated property access:

```
ed.rta_to_arr_paste = function(ele, cur_style) {

    var child_arr = ele.childNodes;

    if(!(is_set(cur_style))) {
        cur_style = {};
    }

    for(var i = 0, l = child_arr; i <l; i++) {
        var child = child_arr[i];
        if(child.nodeType == 1) {
            // this will always be true, because `el.style` returns an object
            // so comparing it does not make sense. Maybe just override it always
            if(cur_style != child.style) { 
                cur_style = child.style;
            }
            // doesn't need to be called for other nodes
            ed.rta_to_arr_paste(child, cur_style); 
        } 
        else if(child.nodeType == 3) {
            var value = child.nodeValue;
            for(var n = 0, ln = value.length; n < ln; n++) {
                ed.add_single_char(value.charAt(n), cur_style);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tyler: You're welcome. I cannot say whether it really helps though, we would need more information/code ;) But these are general tips to reduce unnecessary work/overhead.

Comment: @Tyler: Please have a look at my last update. If you could try it, I would be interested if it really works better for you.

Comment: I just saw it, and if it applies I will certainly try it. The function I wrote should be able to handle very large pieces of code/text so ANYTHING that can improve performance will be implemented. I'll keep you posted in this space. Hopefully will have some data within the hour.

Comment: @Tyler: I just tried again. Unfortunately setting the generated string as HTML takes away all the performance you gained by using `replace`. But you can still try...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching the DOM for an element on every call. I would think you would instead attach an event to the DOM elements in something like onload (or better yet use jquery document.ready). I would also (as a minor refactor) first check to make sure  you have children ( child_arr.length > 0) prior to call the for loop (this may be totally insignificant but best practice)